# How to use Parallel.ForEach with a List?

Tags: c#, multithreading, list

I would like to use `Parallel.ForEach` with a `List` but I can't do it.

Here is my current code:

```
class Test1
{
    public static List<string> myList = new List<string>();

    public object myListToArray()
    {
        return myList.ToArray();
    }
}

class Test2
{
    public void Test(){
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Parallel.ForEach(new Test1().myListToArray(), new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 250 }, foo =>
        {
            // do stuff
        }));
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> Unable to derive the type arguments for the 'Parallel.ForEach' method
>   from use. Try to specify the type arguments explicitly.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Why are you using `ArrayList` rather than `List<T>`? Does https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8c29c33b-840d-4255-bb23-2237b5e64d02/how-to-use-parallelforeach-against-arraylist?forum=parallelextensions help?

Comment: Id you really are trapped with the array you should be good with .ToList()

Comment: I agree with @mjwills that you shouldn't use an `ArrayList` these days anymore, originally this comes from a time when a `List<T>` didnt exist. The `List<T>` has a few advantages and features that the `ArrayList` can't offer.

Comment: Thanks guys, but now that I have changed to List<string> what must I do to fix this error ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @mjwills It's pretty the same code, I just changed `ArrayList` to `List<string>`, I also edited my post, thanks.

Comment: @StéphanieAutire why u try to enumerate over object? Your method returns object, so you should change returning type or casst it to collection of explicit type and your collection shoud't be empty I guess.
I read somewhere that Parallel.ForEach inside Task is not good idea, don't remember where, I modified your code, like I said and it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing code doesn't work since `Parallel.ForEach` doesn't know how to iterate over `object` (above code) / `ArrayList` (code in your original post).

```
public void Test(){
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Parallel.ForEach(Test1.myList, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 250 }, foo =>
    {
        // do stuff
    }));
```

will work since `myList` is a generic `List`, which `Parallel.ForEach` knows how to handle.

Comment: For the downvoter - please feel free to leave a comment. I'd love to learn how to improve the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I modified little bit your code, have a look on Test() method,

```
 class Test1
{
    public static List<string> myList = new List<string>() { "11","22","33"};

    public object myListToArray()
    {
        return myList.ToArray();
    }
}



class Test2
{
    public void Test()
    {
        var test = new Test1();
        Parallel.ForEach((test.myListToArray() as IEnumerable<string>), (value) => { Console.WriteLine(value); });

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the benefit of converting a list to an array, then casting to an object, then casting to an ienumerable?

Comment: @mjwills It's comedy. ;-)